# Update Label in Tkinter to prevent overlapping text

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Tkinter and I'm trying to create a simple Button that opens a file dialog box, where the user chooses which CSV file to open. Under the button there is a label that should display the file path for the file that was opened.

When I click on the button once, everything works as expected. However, if I click on it a second time and select a different file, the new filepath overlaps with the previous one, instead of replacing it.

Here is the code for the implementation function (please let me know if you need more bits of code for context):

```
def open_csv_file():
    global df
    global filename
    global initialdir
    initialdir = r"C:\Users\stefa\Documents\final project models\Case A"
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=initialdir,
                                      title='Select a file', filetypes = (("CSV files","*.csv"),("All files","*.*")))
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(initialdir,filename))
    lbl_ok = tk.Label(tab2, text = ' ') #tab2 is a ttk.Notebook tab
    lbl_ok.config(text='Opened file: ' + filename)
    lbl_ok.grid(row=0,column=1)
```

Comment: don't grid the label again, grid it only once and then just config the text of an already gridded label, basically remove the line `lbl_ok.grid(row=0, column=1)` from the function and put it somewhere else so that it is called only once

Comment: @Matiiss If `lbl_ok` is created outside, then using `grid()` inside a function will not change anything.

Comment: @CoolCloud you're right, but then I wonder what OP means by _the new filepath overlaps with the previous one_

Comment: @Matiiss OP is creating `lbl_ok` inside the function, hence there are more objects created. These objects will overlap each other.

Comment: @CoolCloud nvm, I can guess that they mean that another label is created, so basically they should leave out of the function this line: `lbl_ok = tk.Label(tab2, text = ' ')`

Comment: @Matiiss Yes, also `text` can be omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it with `.config()`, create the label instance just once (can then grid as much as you want but probably just do that once too), then just configure the text:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, filedialog


def open_file():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    lbl.config(text=f'Opened file: {filename}')


root = Tk()

Button(root, text='Open File', command=open_file).grid()
lbl = Label(root)
lbl.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a StringVar for this. Here is an example that may help you:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

def openCsv():
    csvPath.set(askopenfilename())

csvPath = StringVar()

entry = Entry(root, text=csvPath)
entry.grid(column=0, row=0)
btnOpen = Button(root, text='Browse Folder', command=openCsv)
btnOpen.grid(column=1, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: don't import everything from `tkinter` and you can also simply config the label

Comment: It has been a quick example of use. But thanks for the feedback @Matiiss!

Comment: doesn't matter if it is a quick example, it has to be correct (way too many people have made the mistake of importing everything and then can't figure out why sth doesn't work), anyways, why are you using `Entry` for showing text, is it in case it is very long?